# Graphing process memory usage on Linux

Tags: linux, memory, process, graph

I'm trying to diagnose a memory leak in a process, and looking for a tool to graph its memory usage over time.

Is there any tool on Linux that supports diagramming in a form similar to Windows PerfMon?

I tried using IBM virtual assistant, but it works only on 32-bit, while I have 64-bit platform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick hack:

```
for((i=0;;++i)) { echo $i $(grep VmSize /proc/$(pidof firefox-bin)/status | grep -o '[0-9]*'); sleep 1 || break; } > data
^C
graph -T X data
```

The same could be done for things other than "VmSize".

Comment: Useless use of `cat`.

Comment: This seems most interesting approach.

1) What I need installed on CentOS for graph to work?

2) Why cat is useless?

Comment: Actually, from what I read so far VMSize seems to show only part of the picture. So far the most useful tool for me was ps_mem from here (http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py).

The only question is how to plot the resulting graph - I just can't find this "graph" tool on Linux.

Comment: Fixed "useless use of `cat`"

Comment: `graph` is from `plotutils` package on Debian.

For CentOS it should be something like http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/plotutils/

You can also request `-T svg` instead of `-T X` if you want to insert the plot somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

We use Cacti, which is the next gen MRTG, to graph system memory usage.

Comment: Can it monitor a single process?

Comment: To monitor a single process, see the documentation on SNMP for adding a custom command to the SNMP values. The use something like ps with grep and/or awk to find the memory values for your process and output it as a value. Then in Cacti, graph this value as a gauge.