# Good free software to track and graph memory and CPU usage on Windows?

Tags: windows, memory-usage, monitoring

[There](https://serverfault.com/questions/163563/a-monitoring-tool-that-captures-processes-memory-usage-cpu-usage-etc-over-time) [are](https://serverfault.com/questions/70051/a-simple-option-for-graphing-cpu-usage-on-a-remote-linux-server) [many](https://serverfault.com/questions/185804/monitor-and-graph-cpu-usage-per-process-and-per-thread) [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/3104/simple-tool-to-graph-memory-usage) [on](https://serverfault.com/questions/123152/graphing-process-memory-usage-on-linux) Linux memory tracking, but I haven't seen any for Windows. In my case however its a Windows XP Pro box I need to track the memory and CPU usage of.

The reason I need it is due to a server program I'm trying that is eating all my processor and some of my memory which is freezing my RDP session and System Explorer and even makes it difficult to login physically.

As this is a very constrained server I'm working off of (768 MB RAM with Pentium 4 which disappears with this program), I need a program that *doesn't* run/require a webserver. I can give it a MySQL database if necessary however.

Is there any suggestions for such a program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one off debugging, you should use perfmon - it's included in windows. You can setup a counters to run in the background and collect data then analyze it later.

[Microsoft Explains it how just as good as anyone](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305610)

Comment: Hmm... will investigate. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes. tHis is the reason it is not asked for - in Linux it is not part of the core OS. Simple performance tracking is part of windows, the perfmon and collection data sets in current version are good to collect.

Comment: @TomTom @Zypher Quick question: Both computers are Windows XP Pro SP3 full updated. Yet when I connect the Computer Management console remotely through VPN to the target computer, I get a "The specified program requires a newer version of Windows". What gives? They are both the same version! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

check [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) written by Mark Russinovich

Comment: Need *logging*, not live monitoring. Something like the CPU graphs that many Linux tools do. And I've compared Process Explorer to System Explorer in the past, and I prefer System Explorer. Much better interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your requirements, but have you considered [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) of the Sysinternals package?

Comment: See comment to matcheek, I need logging, not live monitoring. Like the CPU graphs that the Linux equivalents do.